# Why can't i render smoke with my AMD graphic card

Tags: rendering, gpu, opencl

When I try to render smoke one GPU it just gives me an OpenCL error, on the CPU its just fine.

I have a ATI HD 7850 2GB ddr5 OC (gtx970 just fried) and since I installed the graphic card I can't work with smoke.

Can someone tell me if Blender supports smoke rendering with AMD GPU?
If so then what is happening to me??

Thank you guys in advance

[image: ATI smoke render FAIL]

Answer (score 5):

Not currently supported, I'm afraid.

You can see the list of supported features over at the [Blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html)

As of Blender 2.78a, October 2016:

`Feature                    CPU                 CUDA (NVIDIA GPU)   OpenCL (AMD GPU)`

`Basic Shading              ✔                   ✔                   ✔`

`Transparent Shadows        ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`Motion Blur                ✔                   ✔                   ✔`

`Hair                       ✔                   ✔                   ✔`

`Volume                     ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`**Smoke / Fire             ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`Subsurface Scattering      ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`Open Shading Language      ✔                   ✗                   ✗`

`CMJ sampling               ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`Branched Path integrator   ✔                   ✔                   ✗`

`Displacement/Subdivision   ✔ (experimental)    ✔ (experimental)    ✔ (experimental)`