# Sun Lamp and volumetrics in Blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, light

[image: SUn Lamp in Cycles]

I create an cave in the hole I add an sun lamp and set into node by using emission shader in the strength I set it to 155 value but I'm not satisfy in the light strength and i'll try to add more strength but still the same result. see my picture references of my problem. thank you

Comment: Are you using World Volumetrics? As far as I know those are known to cause trouble with sun lamps, because the sun is considered to be at an infinite distance, so the worlds absorbs all its intensity. Also make sure you don't have *Light Clipping* enabled in Rendering Path settings.

Comment: My world setting just a color yellow-strength :50  and in volume set to none. but I add an Cube and set as a volume scattering and absorption.

Comment: This is basic volumetrics rendering issues you can easily learn about by watching a couple tutorials to learn how it works.

Comment: ill try to delete a sun lamp and the volumetric scattering object and create new sun lamp still the same

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68668/volumetric-lighting-is-not-working/68671#68671

Comment: change your light to a point light or a spot light or make a cube (or any other closed mesh) that surrounds the scene and use volume scatter on it as a volumetrics domain.