# World Shader Principled Volume Node Issues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, pbr

I'm attempting to set up an underwater scene in Cycles by using the world shaders. My node setup isn't very complicated, it's just a principled volume node with the usual background node.The problem is that any density value above 0 completely blackens the whole scene. I want my scene to have an atmospheric look but still allows light to pass through.
This is the scene with density set to 0:

[image]

And this is the scene with .001 density:

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is. I have a pretty strong sun light source in the scene, and this has never been a problem for me before. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It's probably a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78446/sun-lamp-and-volumetrics-in-blender-cycles